# kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 (ubuntu 18.04lts)

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I'm a newbie in ubuntu.

I want to get help because I'm facing a kernel panic problem like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d53EQ.jpg)

So I googled and found some solutions and tried.

**Solution1.** Tried another version of kernel and its recovery mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcKS1.png)

I tried all of them. And they showed same kernel panic and exitcode=0x00000100.

**Solution2.** Made Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Live USB and tried to boot with USB.

But my computer displayed nothing then.

**Solution3.** Tried to boot manually in grub2 command line following this link.
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux/

But in grub, I couldn't found any sda or other device in `/dev` directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sKT6.png)

Thanks for reading and apologize for my poor English.

Comment: Did I missed something during trying these solutions?
Or are there something other solutions that I can try?

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First check your file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then test your memory...**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But in my case, I booted with Live USB, and entered "Try Ubuntu without installing", but then monitor displays nothing.. so I cannot try your solution.

Comment: @S.W.Kim You have other problems then. Laptop or Desktop? How is your monitor connected... VGA? HDMI? Display port? Any adapters used? What kind, and how old, is the monitor?

Comment: @S.W.Kim Try this... whilst booting the Ubuntu Live, at the very beginning, look for a keyboard icon in the lower-center of your screen. If memory serves me, you can either click on the keyboard icon, or hit the SPACE BAR or ESC or SHIFT key on your keyboard, then select the NOMODESET option.

Comment: I'm using desktop with GIGABYTE aorus mainboard and nvidia GPU(2080ti). And it's connected to monitor with HDMI cable.

Comment: @S.W.Kim Try the NOMODESET suggestion.

Comment: @S.W.Kim Does your GB have an on-board video port? VGA or HDMI?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!!
https://youtube.com/shorts/NXXVW5EVVw0?feature=share
This is what I'm facing.. I tried ESC, SHIFT, SPACE BAR, but it does not show anything

Comment: HDMI cable is connected between GPU and monitor. If I connect monitor and mainboard directly, monitor does not show anything.

Comment: I think I have to clear this hardware problem and try your solution. Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: @S.W.Kim It took a little digging... but when booting the Ubuntu Live USB, get to the Language screen and hit F6, and you'll see the NOMODESET option. This is due to your Nvidia card.

Answer (score 0):

Solved all my issues by buying a USB 3. Micro SD reader. Was getting Kernal panic with the generic USB 2. Card reader supplied  Looked on all sorts of forums. Everything pointed to an issue with the SD card. Flashed 3. Always same issue. All running smoothly now.