# Ubuntu 22.04 is stuck at boot screen

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

My system got stuck at the following screen when trying to boot into kernel image linux 5.15.0-88-generic:

[image: 5.15.0-88-generic boot screen]

I tried booting the previous version of the image (5.15.0-87-generic) and got to this screen:

[image: 5.15.0-87-generic boot screen]

I then tried booting into recovery mode and the boot process stops at the message "end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100". See screenshot:

[image: Kernel panic]

I have tried the suggestions given in this link [kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000100-ubuntu-18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390355/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000100-ubuntu-18):

1. Did a memtest and result is a pass.
2. Boot from a live usb stick and did a fsck on the boot partition. No errors were found but still unable to boot.

I have also tried repairing my grub by running `grub-install` on the boot partition. In still no luck at booting up.