# ubuntu kernel panic and Problems

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, kernel

problem:

```
[0.146408] x86/cpu: UMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[0.1464111] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sda6: clean, 1303675/7913472 files, 28367522/31622144 blocks 
run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init': No such file or directory 
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init': No such file or directory 
run-init: can't execute /etc/init': Permission denied
[1.232031] Kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 [
[1.232054] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: run-init Not tainted 5.15.0-89-generic #99 20.04.1-Ubuntu
[1.232077] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME 2390-P, BIOS 2606 10/24/2019 
[1.232102] Call Trace:
[1.232111] <TASK>
[1.232119] dump_stack_lul+0x4a/0x63
[1.232146] dump_stack+0x10/0x16
[1.232146] panic+0x15c/0x334
[1.232158] do_exit.cold+0x50/0xa0
[1.232170] do group_exit+0x4 exit+0x43/0xb0
[1.232183] x64_sys_exit t_group+0x18/0x20
[1.232196] do_syscall_64+0x59/0xce
[1.232209] ? handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0
[1.232222] ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3d/0x1c0
[1.232238] ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1e0/0x660
[1.232252] ? irgentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x20
[1.232268] ? irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
[1.232281] ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x170
[1.232295] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x62/0xcc
[1.232311] RIP: 0033:0x7f160ef88146
[1.232323] Code: fa 41 b8 e7 00 00 00 be 3c 00 00 00 eb 15 66 of 1f 44 00 00 89 d7 89 f0 of 05 48 3d 00 fo ff ff 77 22 f4 89 d7 44 89 co of 05 <48> 3d 00 fo ff ff 76 e2 f7 d8 64 1.2323711 RSP: 002b:00007ffdd5444848 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG RAX: 00000000000000e7
[1.232393] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007f160f08d8a0 RCX: 00007f160ef88146 
[1.232413] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 0000000000000001 
[1.232433] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 00000000000000e? R09: ffffffffffffff80 
[1.232452] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007f160f08d8a0 
[1.232471] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 00007f160f0962e8 R15: 0000000000000000 
[1.232491] </TASK>
[1.232563] Kernel Offset: 0x2fe00000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range:     0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[1.232593] ---[ end Kernel panic- not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 1---
```

Story:
i command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

after, the output of the monitor became weird. And all the programs slowed down.
I understand that 'nvidia-driver' is the cause. I removed nvidia-driver and installed nvidia-driver-525.
It worked normally, but It did not serve my purpose.

i removed 525 and installed 535 also command `sudo reboot`. And the kernel panic of the above image was output.

What should I do?

Additional Information :
uname -r :
5.13.0-30-generic

ubuntu version : Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS \n \l

I tried :

1. [kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 (ubuntu 18.04lts)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390355/kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init-exitcode-0x00000100-ubuntu-18)

   - The first command `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6` had a change in Ubuntu, but the same error still occurred.
   - Has not changed since then first command
2. [How To Fix Kernel Panic Error in Ubuntu 18.04: Attempting to Kill Init!](https://devicetests.com/fix-kernel-panic-error-ubuntu-1804)

   - STEP2 (From the GRUB menu, choose “Additional Options,” then “Recovery Mode,” and then “Root access) : Kernel panics when accessing recovery mode ( In all kernel versions )
3. [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

   - If i command `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`, A lot of linux-image-x.xx.x-xx-generic are printed (5.11.0-27 ~ 5.15.0-89).
   - if i tried command `update-initramfs -u -k 5.15.0-89-generic` :
     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 75: modprobe: not found
     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 76: modprobe: not found
     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 75: modprobe: not found
     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 76: modprobe: not found
     ...
     ...
     E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
     update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic with 1.
   - after I tried : Create free space to create new intraf images. I command `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic`. But if i command `update-initramfs -u -k 5.15.0-89-generic` ->

     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 75: modprobe: not found

     /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: 76: modprobe: not found

     ...

     E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
     update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic with 1.

Comment: If you can get to a root shell, then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install kmod` which I guess technically you wouldn't need sudo for if root but I digress.  Installing kmod should restore modprobe ability. Also, try booting into an older kernel. If 525 works fine then uninstall the current one and reinstall 525. Check with the Nvidia website to see what version your specific card should be using but do not download any packages from Nvidia as the proprietary nvidia packages are available through the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: On that note, what's your exact Nvidia card make and model?

Comment: @mchid Thanks your comment. I was desperate for help.

If you can get to a root shell :
Do you mean after `sudo chroot /mnt`?  
[I tried](https://pastebin.com/5WGzgWka)

Comment: I'll leave it in case : second [tried](https://pastebin.com/wdtREFbM)

Comment: Kernel panic occurs in all kernel versions. (advanced options for ubuntu)

Comment: Since [I assume] you're running this from a live system, [you may need to run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703887/update-initramfs-is-disabled-live-system-is-running-without-media-mounted-on-r): `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools` Also, check if you have modprobe by running `which modprobe` or `whereis modprobe` and `file /sbin/modprobe`

Comment: Also and for something like this, we usually run: `for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt/$i; done` and it looks like you pretty much did that but `/run` is missing. So I'm not sure if `/run` is necessary here but again, it's usually mounted.

Comment: Sadly, the result was failire.  When i commaned `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools`, `No such file or directory` is displayed.

but I was able to find `update-initramfs` by runnung `ls` in the `/usr/bin` .
[I tried](https://pastebin.com/ipHXDDDH)

Comment: I serach in relation to `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools: no such file or directory` and `command not found`. but i didn't find anything useful

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you need to run the command before you do the chroot.

Comment: Is it correct to run the commands in this order? [tried](https://pastebin.com/R2Mzgb5P)
I've tried many things. But still not running. 

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: I'll leave it in case : [second](https://pastebin.com/qgMwHPjf)

Thank you again.